# How to see set flags in MSVS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

Suppose I have a variable of type `enum` which is the `|` of multiple set flags:

```
EnumType var = ENUM_OPTION1 | ENUM_OPTION2;
```

If only one flag is set, the watch window correctly shows it. If I set more, I'll get an integral value in the watch window. I know why this is happening, but **is there any way to display all flags set during debugging?**

So instead of having

```
var     |         3
```

in the watch window, I'd have

```
var     |         ENUM_OPTION1, ENUM_OPTION2
```

or similar.

I'm also using Visual Assist X, so I'd take solutions involving it, if there are any.

Comment: AFAIK these flags are dissolved with compilation phase.only thing that will remain is series of ORed values.(Not sure if there is any other way)

Comment: @Anonymous well, VS is smart enough to display the value of a single flag. So even though they are translated to integral types during compilation, that's no reason for the debugger to not be able to do the opposite.

Comment: Well, seems VS2012 would do. But not much help.

Comment: @silvesthu what do you mean? They have this in 2012? Link?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I mean Visual Studio 2012 would show all the flags in watch window.

Comment: Even 2008 seems work. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/03/10/visual-studio-2008-enum-bit-flags-visualization.aspx

Comment: It works for a native enum, provided the value fits into enum. Are you using managed enum?

Comment: @Ajay nope, native. But it doesn't seem to work. Maybe it has to be in that format (i.e. `1<<2`).